# Time efficiency of the Russian peasant multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

From the standpoint of time efficiency, does it matter whether we multiply n by m or m by n by the [Russian peasant multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Egyptian_multiplication#Russian_peasant_multiplication) algorithm?

Example, when computing 26 *47, is the time efficiency similar to computing 47*26?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the algorithm runs `floor(log2(k))` iterations for a multiplier (first number) of `k`, the run time definitely depends on order. If `n` and `m` lie between the same two consecutive powers of two then they'll take the same number of iterations to complete. Otherwise, always put the smaller number first to minimize run time.

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int russianPeasant(unsigned int a, unsigned int b) { 
    int res = 0;  // initialize result 
    // While second number doesn't become 1 
    while (b > 0) 
    { 
         // If second number becomes odd, add the first number to result 
         if (b & 1) 
             res = res + a; 
         // Double the first number and halve the second number 
         a = a << 1; 
         b = b >> 1; 
     } 
     return res; 
}
```

The algorithm exits the while loop when b becomes 0. The number of times the loop runs is [log2(b)] + 1 times.

And shifting almost takes constant time (1 CPU cycle)

It makes sense to call with the smaller value as b.

**Bonus: Speed Comparision**

I wrote the above code and ran for the same numbers 47 and 26 in a loop for 10**8 times.

With a = 26, b=47, it took an average of 1336852.2 microseconds.

With a = 47, b=26, it took an average of 1094454.4 microseconds.

**Interesting side note:**

Although as @Dillon Davis mentioned, it should take the same number of iterations if their logs are same, I found that it still takes lesser time with smaller number as b.

(All times in micro seconds)
a = 46,b = 36 - 1204240.6
a = 36, b = 46 - 1295766.8

a= 44, b = 36 - 1204266.2
a= 36, b = 44 - 1253821.17.

**TLDR:**
Run with second number smaller (the one in while loop)

Source code from: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/russian-peasant-multiply-two-numbers-using-bitwise-operators/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you implement your Russian Peasant algorithm. It can be:

- `a*b` faster
- `b*a` faster
- no difference

I opt for *no difference*, because mathematically multiplication for real numbers is commutative: `a*b=b*a` and because the end user, when calling your function, will not like to bother about an order of arguments

For that to happen you need to adjust your code like:

```
Let the two given numbers be 'a' and 'b'.
1) If 'b' is greater than 'a' - swap 'a' with 'b'
2) Initialize result 'res' as 0.
3) Do following while 'b' is greater than 0
   a) If 'b' is odd, add 'a' to 'res'
   b) Double 'a' and halve 'b'
4) Return 'res'.
```

This code will have complexity

> O(log₂(min(a,b)))